# yii1 Fatal error: Call to a member function photo() on a non-object in modules\announcement\views\default\info.php on line 4

Tags: yii

```
<pre>
<div id="information">

    <div id="photo" <?php echo $this->isAdmin() ? 'href="'.$this->settingsUrl().'"':'onclick="window.reload();"';?>>
        <?php echo $this->model()->photo('middle');?>
    </div>

    <div id="more-information">
        <?php if($this->isAdmin()):?>
            <div id="case-update">
                <?php
                $caseURL = $this->model()->case ? '/case/record?id='.$this->model()->case_id : $this->settingsUrl();
                echo Yii::app()->getModule('external')->icon('pencil',$htmlOptions=array('href'=>$caseURL,'alt'=>'Update case information'),'Edit case');?>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <table>
            <?php if($this->model()->case):?>
                <?php foreach($this->model()->case->data as $key => $data):?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $data->attribute->name;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->value;?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </table>

    </div>

</div>
</pre>
```

this is Model

```
<?php
class Announcement extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{announcements}}';
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('user_id, name, category_id, description, location_id, address, createdate', 'required'),
            array('user_id, case_id, category_id, location_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('name, address', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            array('id, user_id, case_id, name, category_id, description, location_id, address, createdate', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'category'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'AnnouncementCategories', 'category_id'),
            'case'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Cases', 'case_id'),
        );
    }
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_id' => 'User',
            'case_id' => 'Case',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'category_id' => 'Category',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'location_id' => 'Location',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'createdate' => 'Createdate',
        );
    }

    public function getUrl(){
        return '/announcement?id='.$this->id;
    }
    public function photo($type='small',$htmlOptions=array()){

        $photo = Yii::app()->getModule('files')->image(
            $src=array(
                'id'=>$this->photoid
            ),
            $size=array(
                'type'=>$type,
                'method'=>'crop'
            ),
            $htmlOptions,
            $this->name
        );
        return $photo;
    }
    public function getPhotoId(){
        Yii::import('application.modules.files.models.Files');
        $model = Files::model()->findByAttributes(array('model'=>get_class($this),'item_id'=>$this->id,'name'=>'generalPhoto'),array('order'=>'id DESC'));
        return $model->id;

    }
    public function photos($count = 6){
        Yii::import('application.modules.files.models.Files');
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('model',get_class($this));
        $criteria->compare('item_id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('name','photos');
        $criteria->order = 'id DESC';
        return new CActiveDataProvider('Files', array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>$count,
            ),
        ));

    }
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

this is my Controller

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            //array('dany',
                //'expression'=> "{$this->validate()}",
            //),
        );
    }

    public function validate(){
        if($this->id()) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public static function id(){
        return Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    }

    public function model(){
        return Announcement::model()->findByPk($this->id());
    }

    public function isAdmin(){
        if($this->model()->user_id ==Yii::app()->user->id) return true;
    }

    public function settingsUrl(){
        return '/announcement/record?id='.$this->id();
    }


    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $file = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('photo');

        if($this->isAdmin() && !empty($file)){
            Yii::app()->getModule('files')->upload($file,'Announcement',$this->id(),'photos');
            $this->redirect($this->model()->url);

        }


        $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gor. Welcome to StackOverflow. To add more information, you should edit your question not add an answer. For more info, read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be that model() function does not return an object. (Not sure whether you are using it as a function by mistake.) Modify it as below.

```
public function model($id) {
   $model = Announcement::model()->findByPk($this->id());
   if ($model === null)
     $model = new Announcement();
   return $model;
}
```

**Note: In your view you have used the functions in the Controller. This makes tight coupling between Controller and the View. Ideally Views should be created to use the data sent from the Controller.**

In this sort of a situation what we do is create a model object in the Controller and pass it to the View. Check following for an example.

In Controller:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
   $data=$this->loadModel($id); 
   $this->render('update',array('model'=>$data));
}    

/**
 * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
 * If the data model is not found, a new model is returned.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
 * @return MyExampleModel the loaded model
 */
public function loadModel($id) {
    $model = MyExampleModel::model()->findByPk($id);
    if ($model === null)
        $model = new MyExampleModel();
    return $model;
}
```

View:

```
<?php  $model->photo('middle');?>
```